# onSubmit() form is not working or triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-redux, onsubmit

I'm trying to implement a function that will accept an attribute called customer_name to create a new customer. Here is my code:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { createCustomer, initialCreate } from '../../redux'

const CreateCustomer = ( { createCustomer, initialCreate, userData } ) => {

    const returnNull = () => {
        return null
    }

    const [actionType, setActionType] = useState('')

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        customer_name: ''
    });

    const { customer_name } = formData;

    const [effectRan, setEffectRan] = useState(false)

    const onChange = e => setFormData({
        ...formData,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!effectRan) {
            setEffectRan(true)
            initialCreate()
        }
    }, [effectRan])

    const onClick = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setActionType(e.target.name)
        console.log(actionType)
    };

    const onSubmit = e => {
        console.log('first')
        console.log(actionType);
        e.preventDefault();
        actionType === 'create' ? createCustomer(customer_name) : returnNull();
        initialCreate();
    }
    

    return userData ? (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
                <table className="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Customer Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input 
                                placeholder=''
                                className='form-control'
                                id="InputCustomerName"
                                name="customer_name"
                                value={customer_name}
                                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                                >
                                </input>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button 
                                type="submit" 
                                name="create"
                                className="btn btn-primary"
                                onClick={e => onClick(e)}
                                >Create
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    ) : (
        <div className="text-center">
            <div className="spinner-border" role="status">
                <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    // is authenticated?
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
    userData: state.customer.customer,
    createSuccess: state.customer.createSuccess
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        createCustomer: (customer_name) => dispatch(createCustomer(customer_name)),
        initialCreate: () => dispatch(initialCreate())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (CreateCustomer);
```

The problem is my submit button seems not working, I can't see any information in my console when I clicked the create button. While I can see the information in the onClick method which means the button is clicked.

Comment: Try to change onSubmit function by  `const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setActionType(e.target.name);
    console.log(actionType);
    actionType === 'create' ? createCustomer(customer_name) : returnNull();
    initialCreate();
};`

Comment: Hi @NIKUNJKOTHIYA , thanks for your reply, I just tried, it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I uncommented my code one by one, I found that I can't have two preventDefault() in both onClick and onSubmit.

So, I uncommented the preventDefault() in my onClick() function.

I'm sorry, I'm not very familiar with react.js, I need to look up some information about this preventDefault()